# How to call a shell script from PLSQL program

Tags: oracle, plsql, shell

Could you please let me know how to call a shell script from PLSQL program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And a forth way (on top of Pablo's) [dbms_pipe](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a68001/dbms_pip.htm)

---

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:16212348050

> In Oracle7.0 and up, we can use
>   dbms_pipes to talk to a daemon running
>   outside the  database.  Here is a
>   simple example that uses sqlplus to be
>   the daemon:

```
create or replace procedure host( cmd in varchar2 )
as
    status number;
begin
    dbms_pipe.pack_message( cmd );
    status := dbms_pipe.send_message( 'HOST_PIPE' );
    if ( status <> 0 ) then raise_application_error( -20001, 'Pipe error' );
    end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 7):

You have a couple of options available:

1. Invoke a Java method from within a PL/SQL wrapper.
2. Call a C program as an external procedure from within PL/SQL.
3. Use the new DBMS_SCHEDULER package.

[Here's](http://www.toadworld.com/BLOGS/tabid/67/EntryId/228/How-to-Run-an-OS-Command-from-PL-SQL.aspx) a link with INFO on them.

Comment: In the second solution, is there any other direct way.

Comment: @ChandraBhushan - what do you mean by "there any other direct way"?

Answer (score 2):

Invoking a shell script from PL/SQL using DBMS_SCHEDULER:
Please find the link below 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_execute_shell_script_plsql_procedure.htm

Answer (score 1):

Not listed above, but still applicable: C Code direct library from PL/SQL [from Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:21419917814146). Obviously it would be an execution of a C Wrapper to call out to the Shell script.

Comment: Tom's example is actually just another sample of method #2 i.e. an external procedure.